# use all the space in android full screen mode

Tags: android, android-layout

In android studio when I set fullscreen mode I still can't use all the space in the screen(the space of navigation bar for example).

what should I do?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".Game">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_game"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

the match parent in line 4 and 5 doesn't consider fullscreen mode.

and this is how I make it fullscreen:

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.project" >

        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                        ...
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
                        ...
                </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

or change @style/AppTheme to fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in java file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

You can also do it via `AndroidMenifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```